# Get json from Wt::Http::Request& request

Tags: c++, json, wt

I have problem with json request :(
I have class

```
class ForumCreate : public Wt::WResource
```

and function

```
virtual void handleRequest(const Wt::Http::Request& request, Wt::Http::Response& response)
```

request.contentType() is application/json.
How do I get  json from request?(

Maybe I should use something else to get json? 
Task: User send http-request with json on static url. I need to analize json file and send json-response.

Comment: this is just a quick gues, but handleRequest is probably for an http server.  I would expect you would want something that just takes an Http::Response object, not a request as well.

Comment: Yes, I have http-server. User send http-request on this server. 
And function handleRequest is analyzing this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to parse the data from the input stream provided by

```
std::istream & Wt::Http::Request::in    (       )   const
```

https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1Http_1_1Request.html#a768a65ceb3c0bf013b57c3de04b19041

It should be the raw json text.

Comment: std::string temp7;
 while (std::getline(request.in(),temp7));

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in JSON parser in Wt. I use it like this:

```
Wt::Json::Object bodyContent;

try
{
    Wt::Json::parse(fromIstream(request.in()), bodyContent);
}
catch(std::exception e)
{
    ...
}
```

Where fromIstream is the following:

```
std::string fromIstream(std::istream &stream)
{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> eos;
    return std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), eos);
}
```

Keep in mind that Wt::Json::parse() will throw an exception in case of malformed input. Hope it helps!